# Designing a safety circuit to ignite a pyrotechnic device

Tags: circuit-design

I have been given a project to design a circuit which will ignite a pyrotechnic flare after a certain sequence of events has been detected. The events which must be detected are:

- A specific signal transitions from a short circuit to an open circuit.
- A short pulse signal from a separate detector is received.
- A 5V logic signal transitions from logic 0 to logic 1.

Additionally, the sequence in which these events occur is unknown.

I have a massive interest in electronics but only a limited knowledge which I have gained from my university course (Physics), so I'm struggling to know where to begin with this project.

I need advice on which components the circuit should contain in order to detect these events and if wiring them in a particular way may work better than others. I'm kind of viewing this as a learning experience, any suggestions or explanations offered will be thoroughly appreciated. I will do my best to try to understand!

Comment: Generally pyrotechnic controls will have a human [dead man's switch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dead_man%27s_switch) as well (to avoid creating dead people).

Comment: You've got to design this system to **fail in a safe manner**. Simple electronic circuits can fail open circuit or short circuit so you can't use them as safety controllers. @David's idea of a deadman's switch is one solution. A double-pole deadman's switch cutting both positive and negative legs of the igniter would be safer and it should be the last item in the feed to the igniter - i.e., after any electronic devices. A true deadman's switch will cut the circuit if you let go or if you over-press in reaction to a fright.

Comment: When you say that the  sequence is unknown, should we take that to mean that once all events have  occurred, in any order, we should ignite the device? Should the events be "latched"? In other words, if the circuit transitions from short to open, but then goes back to short, should be "remember" can we still launch when all the other events have occurred? And if so, how long should we wait for all the  events to occur? Forever?

Comment: First google "electronic blasting detonators" and read every link in the first 3 pages.  Then consider your needs starting with safety.  Even if this is a though exercise for the zombie apocalypse of an anarchists training school a detonator has to be safe or it will not get used.  What I have read and heard at trade shows points towards many patented and novel ideas in use.  Each detonator needs to have an energy store, a (typically adjustable electronic) time delay and the safety interlock checks that are used to arm and trigger the detonators.

Comment: This sounds massively problematic from both a definition of action (as per mkeith's comment) and safety point of view. My non-automated model rocket launcher has two separate disable switches (one keyed) before the go button becomes hot...

Comment: Just how much safety you need to evaluate needs a couple of answers for the use case. 1. What will be the effect of inadvertent firing? 2. Is this expected to operate autonomously? The answers to those drive much of what type of solution can be used.

Answer (score 1):

All of these three detection methods can be done with some simple CMOS logic circuits, take a look at flip-flop or set/reset latches as a good place to start.

Each of the three inputs could be separated into individual tests, then be latched and the outputs of the three latches ANDed together, so the ignition would only occur once all three signals are present.

The moment all three are present (and therefore each of the three individual conditions has been met), the AND gate can be used to both trigger the ignition and reset all the latches and return the system to it's standby state ready for the next activation.

Of course, all of this is theoretical and safety needs to be taken into account. In industry, this is usually done with a combination of things, most importantly a dead man's handle (as already described) and using the concept of a second channel of independent control. Often this is done with a software channel (doing all the tests in software, perhaps on a PIC), mixed with a second hardware channel completing the same tests using low-level logic (perhaps CMOS or relay interlocks).

The overall safety of the system is usually designed to meet a particular Performance Level (PLd) as defined in the EU by the Machinery Directive.
Depending on your intentions with the project you will need to comply with a variety of different regulations and directives so of course all of this advice is given with that in mind.

Comment: A multi-channel architecture with voting *may* be required, or as noted, a dead mans switch.

Comment: Thanks, that's really helpful. I love the idea of using an AND gate to ignite the device and also reset the system. Also, I'm not actually building this circuit, it's purely a theoretical task for an interview, although I will bear in mind these regulations exist as obviously I want to present the interviewers with a practical solution. I have to admit I didn't have any knowledge of how logic circuits work prior to being given this project but I have looked into them and I think I understand them. I'm unsure though about which logic gates to use for each detection method, it seems like (cont)

Comment: there are many options available and I don't know how to justify whichever ones I choose to use when I come to explain my solution. Considering that safety is the main objective of this project, that will be my number one concern, but I don't know which circuits would be safest to use?

Comment: The actual implementation of these tests really requires more information for a real-world scenario. For instance take "A short pulse signal from a separate detector is received". How long is the pulse? Do we cancel the "trigger" if the pulse is TOO long, TOO short? What kind of rising edge should we see, etc?